# How to use ndb key with integer_id?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I see the document
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_integer_id

> Returns the integer id in the last (kind, id) pair, or None if the key
>   has an string id or is incomplete.

see I think the id of a key can be a int  ; so I write

```
    r = ndb.Key(UserSession, int(id)).get()
    if r:
        return r.session
```

but the dev_server.py , will always raise

```
  File "/home/bitcoin/down/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_stub_util.py", line 346, in CheckReference
    raise datastore_errors.BadRequestError('missing key id/name')
BadRequestError: missing key id/name
```

I chanage the int(id) -> str(id)

seems right ;

so my question is , How to use ndb key with integer_id ?

the model is

```
class UserSession(ndb.Model):
    session = ndb.BlobProperty()
```

Comment: The code snippets you have should work fine with an integer. There must be something else going wrong here.

Comment: I know it is an old question but I think issue could be solved if you use as string instead of the object when you construct a key: ndb.Key('UserSession', int(id)).

Answer (score 10):

The type of the id you use when *reading* the entity must match the type of the id you used when you *wrote* the entity.  Normally, integer ids are assigned automatically when you write a new entity without specifying an id or key; you then get the id out of the key returned by entity.put().  It is generally not recommended to assign your own integer ids; when the app assigns the keys, the convention is that they should be strings.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to fetch:

```
UserSession.get_by_id(int(id))
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id

If that doesn't work, I suspect that `id` is wrong or empty.

Comment: thanks , https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#numeric_keys , but I see the document write I can use int id

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your variable 'id'.

Your code here should be no problem, and it's better to user long instead of int.

You can try your code on interactive console of development server with specific integer id.

Comment: There is absolutely no advantage to using long instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to identify your entities in the sessions with their keys instead of their ids. There really is no need to extract the ID from the key to identify the session (other than maybe saving a *bit* of memory. I think the way your thinking is based on a RDB. I learned that using the key actually makes entity/session identifications easier.

Answer (score 0):

'id' is also a python builtin function. Maybe you are taking that by mistake.